# Good way to define a method

Tags: c#, methods, code-structure

What is the best / good way to implement method calls.

For eg: From the below which is generally considered as best practice.  If both are bad, then what is considered as best practice.

Option 1 :

```
   private void BtnPostUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getValue();
    }

    private void getValue()
    {
        String FileName = TbxFileName.Text;
        int PageNo = Convert.ToInt32(TbxPageNo.Text);

        // get value from Business Layer
        DataTable l_dtbl = m_BLL.getValue(FileName, PageNo);

        if (l_dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            TbxValue.Text = Convert.ToInt32(l_dtbl.Rows[0]["Value"]);
        }
        else
        {
            TbxValue.Text = 0;
        }
    }
```

Option 2 :

```
    private void BtnPostUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String FileName = TbxFileName.Text;
        int PageNo = Convert.ToInt32(TbxPageNo.Text);

        int Value = getValue(FileName, PageNo);

        TbxValue.Text = Value.ToString();

    }

    private int getValue(string FileName, int PageNo)
    {
        // get value from Business Layer
        DataTable l_dtbl = m_BLL.getValue(FileName, PageNo);

        if (l_dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(l_dtbl.Rows[0]["Value"]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I understand we can pass parameters directly without assigning to a local variable...  My question is more about the method definition and the way it is handled.

Comment: This is from winforms... But the question can be considere in other application types too...

Comment: You should really take a look at C# naming conventions - it will make your code much more readable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're subscribing to the event automatically, I don't think it's particularly bad to have a method with the event handler signature which just delegates to a method which has the "real" signature you need (in this case, no parameters).

If you're subscribing manually, you can use a lambda expression instead:

```
postUpdateButton.Click += (sender, args) => PostUpdate();
```

and then do the work in `PostUpdate`. Whether you then split up the `PostUpdate` into two methods, one to deal with the UI interaction and one to deal with the BLL interaction is up to you. In this case I don't think it matters too much.

How you structure UI logic to make it testable is a whole different matter though. I've recently become a fan of the MVVM pattern, but I don't know how applicable that would be to your particular scenario (it's really designed around Silverlight and WPF).

A couple of other comments though:

- Conventionally, parameters should be camelCased, not PascalCased
- Do you genuinely believe you're getting benefit from prefixing local variables with `l_`? Isn't it obvious that they're local? Personally I'm not keen on most of the variable names shown here - consider naming variables after their *meaning* rather than their *type*.
- Using a `DataTable` to return information is a somewhat error-prone way of doing things. Why can the BLL not return an `int?` to indicate the value (or a lack of value)?

Comment: Thanks for your response, suggestions & comments

Answer (score 1):

here is what i like to to if i don't implement mvc.  and i'm assuming web here.

I'd do option 2 first but instead of having the buttons code set the text id create a property to set the text boxs value.

I do this because if something else sets the textbox value then you are going to duplicate code.  bad if you change a name or control type.

Comment: Do you want me to create 15 Properties in my Form 1 for each TextBox.  What will be the case for other controls?

Comment: I'm just saying that I would never actually have a button even update a textbox.  And yeah, i probably might add 15 properties.  especially if i were massaging the data before posting

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, option 2 is the way to go. Option 1 knows about your form and how to display data on it, which violates the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: Yes but should a buttons event interact with a textbox?  i think maybe adding a property that would in turn set the textbox might be called for.  then again why not implement mvc?

Comment: Well, in my opinion, controls are (and can also be) thigtly coupled in a simple, single, winforms application. In the end, it boils down to how complex the application is and what separations you need.

Comment: An therein lies the problem in simple winforms but the OP doesn't mention winforms and the event looks webforms to me

Comment: These are private methods, both of which presumably live on the form.

Comment: But if need to make the same action happen (like populating the amount field) from elsewhere (in some other event),  I need to again gather the parameter and pass it to the method right..  But in option 1, I can just call the method and it will take care of its need